# How to use a module which needs import statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-agent) in my nodejs app.

the issue is I used a lot of modules with `require` statement before, like:

`const translate = require('google-translate-open-api');`

Now when i want to use the mentioned module using this:

`import { HttpProxyAgent } from 'http-proxy-agent';`

I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

if I use this code to import the module:

`const { HttpProxyAgent }= require('http-proxy-agent');`

I get this error:

> TypeError: createHttpProxyAgent is not a function

How can I use this kind of modules in nodejs app?

Answer (score 1):

in your package.json file add:

```
{
 // ...
 "type": "module",
  // ...
}
```

and then use:

```
import { HttpProxyAgent } from 'http-proxy-agent';
```

you might also need to make changes in other imports which use require keyword.

Comment: Ok, i did this but I get this error: ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead

Comment: So you say I need to change all `require` statements to `import` ?! I wonder if this cause any issues ?

Comment: this will not cause any issue if you switch to import statement

Comment: ok, this may take some time to do all of those but I get back to you soon.. thanks for you help ..

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap `HttpProxyAgent` inside `{}` just like the `import` one.

```
const {HttpProxyAgent} = require('http-proxy-agent');
```

Comment: Not working... TypeError: createHttpProxyAgent is not a function again

Comment: can you show your full code so that we can see where you have called createHttpProxyAgent??

Comment: @RaolmAX Then problem is not the importing. It's where you are using it in your code. Share your code if possible.